# how to upload generic test execution report in a sonarqube server?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

On an application compound by a set of micro services, I used JMeter to perform API tests and users scenario testing (see [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/feedback-cloud-formation-jmeter-use-teach-system-tests-granier-x8iye/?trackingId=flFvMykITw65HUVMfBVGZQ%3D%3D)).

I would like to manage these tests statuses and durations in sonarqube and for that to upload these tests results in sonarqube.

Producing a generic test execution report is easy, the format is quite simple.( see [here](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.8/analyzing-source-code/test-coverage/generic-test-data/) )

```
<testExecutions version="1">
  <file path="testx/ClassOneTest.xoo">
    <testCase name="test1" duration="5"/>
    <testCase name="test2" duration="500">
      <skipped/>
    </testCase>
    <testCase name="test3" duration="100">
      <failure/>
    </testCase>
    <testCase name="test4" duration="500">
      <error/>
    </testCase>
  </file>
</testExecutions>
```

But the documentation explains "Unlike for coverage reports, the files present in the report must be test file names, not source code files covered by tests.".

But in the context of generic test execution report what is a test file name?

JMX files are not JUnit files, if I set the element like `<file  path="jmx/api/scenario1.jmx">` will the sonarqube server accept it as a test file name ?

The version of Sonarqube is sonarqube-10.2.1.78527.

The version of the sonar-scanner is 5.0.1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - referencing jmx in the report won't work, but workaround exists

Now, answering your questions...

1. what is a test file name?

Practically, SonarQube differentiates files by two scopes - sources and tests. Any file which is in 'tests' scope (defined by sonar.tests parameter) is considered as a test file. In the context of *generic test execution report* 'a test file name' means the same - it is a file defined in the 'tests' scope. [See more detales on scopes](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/project-administration/analysis-scope/)

2. will the sonarqube server accept it as a test file name ?

The type of the referenced file matters. SonarQube tries to detect file language and it will fail to do so for '.jmx' (at least in SonarQube CE 9.9). So your **"jmx/api/scenario1.jmx"** will most likely end up with an error **Skipping file ... in the generic test execution report because it doesn't have a known language**  even if you define this file as part of the 'tests' scope. One possible workaround would be to rename .jmx to .xml. That way language check will pass.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I test it. I hoppe that JMeter accepts xml file ...

Comment: Hi @andrepyc, your answer is fine and work perfectly. In the case of a maven project with a module containing the jmx files, the configuration is a bit tricky. The jmx module has to be added in modules list (sonar.modules), since sonar.sources is set to /src/main/java this jmx module has to contain a folder /src/main/java. Then It has to contain a folder /src/test that contains the jmx files. But in the generic report, the file name is defined  relative to the project's base directory (root module) so it has to be jmx/src/test/scenario1.jmx ...

Comment: if I may @andreypc, this link https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-unify-unit-tests-system-indicator-bernard-granier-rp3ff/ provides the context of my question. I achieve to upload coverage report produced by jmx tests and now thanks to your answer I upload test reports.

Comment: How to manage jmx extension is described here : https://community.sonarsource.com/t/what-does-test-file-names-mean-in-generic-test-execution-format/104278